# Where do you put all your solution level (global) tasks? In an otherwise empty project specifically for this purpose?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

There are multiple tasks I want to run, depending on the solution configuration, when someone builds my solution:

- In Release configuration, run Doxygen for the whole solution (doxygen.exe ....)
- In Debug and Release configuration, run StyleCop for the whole solution (invoke StyleCop target)
- In Debug configuration, run FxCop for the whole solution (fxcop.exe ...)
- and more

These are all solution level (global) tasks, so it doesn't make sense to me to put this in every project file. Seems like this would be a common problem, so how do you deal with it?

I'm thinking I can create an empty project, make sure every other project depends on it and put all the solution level tasks in that...?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to put such tasks in a .targets file and reference them from my main projects (roughly the ones not producing a library). I might also create `Target`s in that .targets file that would combine a subset of the common tasks. That way, some of my projects may conveniently run `sharedtask1` and `sharedtask2`, whereas others run `sharedtask1` and `sharedtask3`, because I just add `DependsOnTargets="Shared12"` and `DependsOnTargets="Shared13"` (obviously, I would try to pick descriptive names).

These articles have some good advice on organising your msbuild tasks:

[Best Practices For Creating Reliable Builds, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd419659.aspx)

[Best Practices For Creating Reliable Builds, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dd483291.aspx)

**EDIT**

To run some tasks only once use incremental builds as described in the second article above:

- In the common .targets file I hinted to above, create a task that has all your files as Inputs and some dummy marker file as output.
- Make that task do the actual work you are interested in *and* update the marker file.
- Make all your projects depend on the newly created task

When the solution is built, the first project will kick off the task mentioned above, the task will output a marker file and, as long as your input files don't change for the rest of the build, that task won't run again. 
Now, the drawbacks to this are

- if your build causes files to be generated or altered in the process, the task will run multiple times
- the task will run even if you are only doing a build of a single project. This might actually be the "correct" behaviour if you are generating documentation. If you want to avoid that I think you will have to really fine-tune your msbuild files, but I get the impression that that's what you are trying to avoid.
- the task will run before things have been built, so any task that depends on the to-be-built versions of assemblies will be out of luck

To address the last issue you will have to give up building from VS and instead invoke a custom task, that will build the solution and then execute one or more custom tasks in sequence) using msbuild.exe from the command line. I realise that it is probably not the developer experience you are looking for.

Comment: Generating documentation (etc.) isn't exactly a shared task I want to invoke from several projects. I want to invoke it once, when the solution is built. Does your solution address that?

Answer (score 3):

This question assumes you want everything building every time, which in practice I haven't found to be the case. Currently the team I'm working with ate very sensitive to build times.

As a result I suggest you consider a build not as a single thing but as having several flavours. There's the "does it build?" build, for which I would map Build Selection (current project only) to a key for, until I started using reshaper. There's a "let's test it build" for people who aren't unit testing (including those developing non testable ui changes) and if course then there is the "Everything and the kitchen sink build" where documentation, stylecop and any other metrics can be obtained.

For this reason, I would suggest the use of a build server. Put your additional targets out of the way and use them when all your other work is completed. I would recommend TeamCity's pre-tested commit feature as a great way to enable your team to test that they don't break and build failure conditions such as coverage decrease.

Also if you are searching for even more rapid builds at development time then I recommend the use of NCrunch which has a highly optimised build process that runs within a second or so of you editing your file, or ContinuousTests.

Comment: Some of the tasks we may want to run every single build, others not so much. I was thinking I could use the $(Configuration) variable to say what I want to build when.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting I should create a target per task, e.g. StyleCopTarget, FxCopTarget, DoxygenTarget and then invoke these when appropriate?

Comment: Configurations are very useful, but since you are using msbuild then targets are probably more appropriate.

Comment: Given that can always create a wrapper target that calls all the other targets then that is a perfectly logical thing, however I was just suggesting to make sure you call what you want when you need it, not everything every time. :-)

Comment: Ok, so I create targets. Now where do I invoke/call them, so that the proper tasks are run when someone builds the solution (either locally or on build server)?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to create an empty project called "Build.csproj".  Place it in the solution and make it depend on all other projects. Then for simple tasks you can use the post-build event to run your tools. If you need to more advanced you can modify the project's Build target.

There are a couple of nice things about it:

1. It is simple and easy to setup and understand.
2. It does not generally interfere with debugging since you set a different project as the startup.
3. You can create configurations that ignore the project.
4. Assuming you stick to post build events it allows VS integration without warnings.

Comment: I think I want to do most tasks after the whole solution is built. In your example, wouldn't my tasks be executed before the whole solution is built?

Comment: Having Build.csproj depend on all the other projects means that it will build after all other projects.  So the 'whole solution' is built first and then the post build of build.csproj will run.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not create a solution folder containing the various scripts that perform your build followup tasks on the selected targets, and call them from the post build event of your projects? I.e.

- PostBuildScripts (solution folder)

  - FxCop.Debug.Target
  - FxCop.Release.Target
  - StyleCop.Release.Target
  - StyleCop.Release.Target
  - Doxygen.Debug.Target
  - Doxygen.Release.Target
  - Others.Release.Target
  - Others.Release.Target

... etc ...

These scripts make the calls to run your followup task against the target build type; if you don't actually want to run it against a certain build type, just leave it empty.

Postbuild in your projects:

/PostBuildScripts/FxCop.$(ConfigurationName).Target

/PostBuildScripts/Doxygen.$(ConfigurationName).Target

/PostBuildScripts/StyleCop.$(ConfigurationName).Target

/PostBuildScripts/Others.$(ConfigurationName).Target

... etc ...

Comment: One of the things I'm trying to avoid is editing of every single project file. I shouldn't have to do that, when the tasks I want to do are on a solution (global) level.

Comment: Visual Studio does not have explicit support for Solution-wide post-build events, but it is possible to do what you want: http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2011/02/easily-add-pre-and-post-build-tasks-for-a-visual-studio-solution.html.

The solution folder is a virtual folder -- it does not live in a physical location on the disk; it's just a list of folder/item aliases.

Comment: "The only drawback (which it shares with the first approach) is that this script is only for manual execution. Building from within Visual Studio can't take advantage of it."

Comment: The link in my previous comment shows how to make the solution post-build script execute automatically.

Comment: I'm embarrased. I missed that bit.

Answer (score 1):

In our solution we put such build actions in our startup project, cause we don't want to put it in every projects and our running project reference all other projects. So all actions that is run on postbuild actions of this project will be done after all other projects already done.